# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'CGPoint'

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, iphone-sdk-3.0

My project compiles and runs fine unless I try to compile my Unit Test Bundle it bombs out on the following with an "**Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'CGPoint'**" error on line 5:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Force.h"

@interface WorldObject : NSObject {
    CGPoint coordinates;
    float altitude;
    NSMutableDictionary *forces;
}

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint coordinates;
@property (nonatomic) float altitude;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *forces;

- (void)setObject:(id)anObject inForcesForKey:(id)aKey;
- (void)removeObjectFromForcesForKey:(id)aKey;
- (id)objectFromForcesForKey:(id)aKey;
- (void)applyForces;

@end
```

I have made sure that my Unit Test Bundle is a target of my **WorldObject.m** and it's header is imported in my testing header:

```
#define USE_APPLICATION_UNIT_TEST 1

#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Force.h"
#import "WorldObject.h"


@interface LogicTests : SenTestCase {
    Force *myForce;
    WorldObject *myWorldObject;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` instead of `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` in your header file (the top file in your question).

Comment: Or `<CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>`

Comment: I see what's happening now.  It works when I compile my app, because UIKit is imported in my view controller, but not when it stands alone in my unit test bundle.

Thanks!!